# Facebook UI for making a wall post?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Note: I'm using version 3.0.2.b of the Facebook Android SDK. I don't want to use any deprecated classes/methods.

Is there a standardized way to prompt the user for text to enter in a wall post--such as when sharing a photo?

FBDialog is deprecated. I don't see anything else obvious in the [Android SDK Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0) that would have such a UI. Even the [tutorial to publish a wall post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/) assumes you already have the string you want to publish.

It's just odd that they provide the full sign-in dialog, but would leave it to the developers to create the UI for likes, sharing, wall posts, etc.

So again, my question is--do I need to create my own UI to prompt the user to enter the message they want published to their wall, or is there something in the SDK to standardize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a DialogListener and use it properly when accessing the facebook.dialog() method.

See this article for more help: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

```
public void postToWall() {
// post on user's wall.
facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
});
}
```

[image: http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/android_facebook_posting_to_wall.png]

Or you can create your own function that creates a dialog with a TextView inside where the user inserts it's own message and then pass this message to the Facebook object inside the Bundle with the parameters! <- This is a WorkAround if you dont want to use the deprecated Listener!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's deprecated--as I stated in my question, the challenge is to find a new solution that isn't deprecated.

Comment: Then i guess the next solution is to create a custom Dialog, call it with a function of your own and make it return a String variable.

Comment: I was afraid of that... that there is no recommended built-in UI, and developers have the choice of using the deprecated Facebook dialogs or creating their own. If you change your answer to that, I'll accept it.

Comment: Changing my answer to what?

Comment: To note that the developer can either create their own UI, or use the deprecated API that you referenced in your post

Comment: Ok i will do it now, although the Official SDK of Facebook doesnt mention any deprecation on that Listener.

Comment: The SDK documentation is extremely sparse or even outdated in places, yes--but look at the source files, or try to use them, and you'll see they're deprecated. Surprised me at first too.

Comment: The last update was at November the 27th of 2012 specifically for the DialogListener and that is surprising. I use facebook integration into my main app but never used DialogListener cause i send a custom message!

Comment: Accepted as the only answer

Comment: Although now that the sdk v3.0  is out i can provide you another solution :P